# Inspecting a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, inspect

When I want to debug the following hash, it returns `try2test2`.

```
dictionary = {
  "test" => 2,
  "try" => 2
}

puts dictionary
# => try2test2
```

Are there any other ways to do it so that it will give you the full list like `{'test': 2, 'try': 2}`?

Comment: Have you tried `dictionary.inspect`?

Comment: Which ruby version did you use? `Hash#to_s` should not return like `try2test2`.

Comment: dictionary.inspect works! thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As V. Melnychuk mentioned, JSON is a good option, just remember to import the "json" module first:

```
require "json"
dictionary.to_json
```

in general, you can retreive a readable string version of an object by calling
inspect on it:

```
dictionary.inspect
```

finally, there is a "pp" module to pretty-print variable (pretty much like the pprint module in python):

```
require "pp"
pp dictionary
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert object to JSON

```
dictionary.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do `p dictionary` which sends `inspect` by default:

```
dictionary = {
  "test" => 2,
  "try" => 2
}

p dictionary      # => {"test"=>2, "try"=>2}
```